# Embedding html in php class file

Tags: php, class

I have a calendar class which outputs a HTML table with a table cell representing a day of the month, however should I be embedding HTML into a class file. My concern is that if I ever have to amend the HTML (i.e add an ID to an element), then I would have to adjust the class file.

I currently dont use the MVC pattern in my project so having a view is not an option.

My cut down class files is as follows (for this example I have assumed that 1 month is 4 weeks):

```
class calendar {

function __construct(){

}

function output() {
    print "<table>";
    for ($week=0; $week < 4; $week++) {
        print "<tr>";
        for ($day=0; $day < 7; $day++) {
            print "<td></td>";
        }
        print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
}
```

Are there any other methods which I haven't thought about which would keep the HTML separate from the class file
Thanks in advance

Comment: include the calendar class in a php file (index.php), and use: $cal = new Calendar(); , now you can do this: $cal->week; (depends on how you wrote the class), maybe 'print_r($cal)' first

Comment: maybe check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: This question does not fit the embedded tag see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info. Tag removed

Answer (score 3):

The most simple templating

```
// myTemplate.phtml
<div><?php echo $xy; ?></div>

// SomewhereElse.php
class MyClass {
  public function myMethod () {
    $xy = 'something';
    include('myTemplate.phtml');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One very popular solution for your problem is to use http://www.smarty.net/ or order template engine in order to split your presentation logic from business logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could have some sort of HTML helper class that generates your code. The class can have `createTable`, `addRow`, `closeTable`, `createForm`, `addField`, etc.. The main properties are sent in the method call, and the constants are coded directly into the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply write an HTML file and put placeholders there.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
<?php echo output() ?>
...
```